# Lotusscript: Retrieve the images in the body of an email

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

In my agent, I try to retrieve all the files that are in the current email. My attached code works fine, except for the images in the body of the email. I manage to retrieve all the files and images that were attached to the email except the pictures that were copied and pasted in the middle of the email text. Here is my code:

```
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim CurrentDocColl As NotesDocumentCollection

    Set db = Session.Currentdatabase
    Set CurrentDocColl = db.Unprocesseddocuments
    Set doc = CurrentDocColl.Getfirstdocument
    While Not doc Is Nothing
        Set item = doc.GETFIRSTITEM("Body")
        If doc.HasEmbedded Then
            ForAll attachment In item.EmbeddedObjects
                Call attachment.ExtractFile (pathname & "\" & attachment.Name)
            End ForAll
        End If
        Set doc=CurrentDocColl.Getnextdocument(doc)
    Wend
```

How can I retrieve these images?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have an agent that does a lot of that, but it's not short.  What you have to do is run the document through an XML DomParser, walk down the DOM tree and when you find a node with "JPEG" or "PNG" in the name (the inline images themselves), stream the data to a file and save it.  The code is combination of an agent I found online (which I couldn't find again, otherwise I would give credit) and work I've done.  You won't be able to copy/paste this sample code and expect it to work, I've removed things (like declaring variables and supporting functions) for brevity.

```
    Sub Initialize
        Dim dxlExp As NotesDXLExporter
        Set dxlExp = s.CreateDXLExporter
        Call dxlExp.setInput(Doc)
        Set DomParser=s.CreateDOMparser()
        Call DomParser.Setinput(dxlExp)
        Dim dxlImp As NotesDXLImporter
        Set dxlImp = s.Createdxlimporter()
        Call dxlImp.Setinput(domParser)
        Call dxlImp.SetOutput(db)
        On Event PostDomParse From DomParser Call DomInputProcessed
        Call dxlExp.Process
    End Sub
    
    Sub DomInputProcessed(DomParser As NotesDomParser)
        Dim DomNode As NotesDomNode
        Set DomNode = DomParser.Document
        Call walkTree(DomParser, DomNode)
        Exit Sub
    End Sub
    
    Sub walkTree (DomParser As NotesDOMParser, node As NotesDOMNode)
         Select Case node.NodeType
         Case DOMNODETYPE_DOCUMENT_NODE:        ' If it is a Document node
             domParser.Output( "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"+LF )
    
             Set child = node.FirstChild   ' Get the first node
             Dim numChildNodes As Integer
             numChildNodes = node.NumberOfChildNodes
    
             While numChildNodes > 0 
                 Set child = child.NextSibling ' Get next node
                 numChildNodes = numChildNodes - 1                  
                 Call walkTree(DOMParser, child)
             Wend
    
         Case DOMNODETYPE_DOCUMENTTYPE_NODE:   ' It is a <!DOCTYPE> tag
             domParser.Output("<!DOCTYPE "+ node.NodeName+ ">" + LF)
    
         Case DOMNODETYPE_TEXT_NODE:           ' Plain text node
             value = xmlReplace(node.NodeValue)
             domParser.Output(value)
    
         Case DOMNODETYPE_ELEMENT_NODE:        ' Most nodes are Elements
        Select Case node.NodeName
            Case "jpeg"
                 Dim jpegfile As String 
                 ' Step 1, write the MIME file
                 Dim base64node As NotesDOMNode
                 Set base64Node = node.Firstchild
                 Dim base64Out As NotesStream
                 Set base64Out = s.createStream()
                 Dim bytesWritten As Long
                 bytesWritten = base64Out.Writetext(base64Node.NodeValue)
                 ' Step 2, Read the MIME file and decode it.
                 Set db=s.currentdatabase
                 Set doc=db.createDocument()
                 Set m=doc.Createmimeentity("Image1")
                 Call m.setContentFromText(base64Out, "image/jpeg", 1727)
                 Call m.Decodecontent()
                 Dim JPEGOut As NotesStream
                 Set JPEGOut = s.createStream()
                 jpegFile = RandomFileName(baseDir, ".jpg")
                 JPEGOut.open(jpegFile)
                 Call m.Getcontentasbytes(JPEGOut, True)
                 Call JPEGOut.Close()
                 attachmentNamesStr = attachmentNamesStr + jpegFile + "~"  
                 ' Step 3, remove the jpeg and its child node
                 ' We do this by just not sending anything to the DomParser output.

           Case "png"
      ' Same as JPEG except it's PNG.

    
        End Select
    End Select  'node.NodeType
    End If        'Not node.IsNull
End Sub
```